# Subscriber add returns error 13

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am currently working to integrate with the API using the format shown at: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/xml_api/xml_api_calls_and_sample_code/subscriber_management/subscriber_add/).

I need to understand what I am doing wrong. For context we are connecting to https://api.exacttarget.com/integrate.aspx and attempting to add a subscriber.

I'm not clear on what value should be set for the  tag, but I assume it should be the group ID found in My Groups -> [our group name] (using the subscribers -> all subscribers link in the email tab from the dashboard, found at https:// mc.s4.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Marketing%20Cloud%20Dashboard).

```
Request:
qf=xml&xml=<exacttarget>
    <authorization>
        <username>[our user name]</username>
        <password>[our password]</password>
    </authorization>
    <system>
        <system_name>subscriber</system_name>
        <action>add</action>
        <search_type>listid</search_type>
        <search_value>12345</search_value>
        <search_value2/>
        <values>
            <Email__Address>test@test.com</Email__Address>
            <Full__Name>Johny Test</Full__Name>
        </values>
    </system>
</exacttarget>

Response:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<exacttarget>
    <system>
        <subscriber>
            <error>13</error>
            <error_description>An error occurred while attempting to save your subscriber data</error_description>
        </subscriber>
    </system>
</exacttarget>
```